# How to connect to a phoneix framework app locally by telnet?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, telnet, cowboy

I would like to use telnet to test my phoenix app, but it shows `Connection closed by foreign host.` very quickly and telnet exits.

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 4000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

The phoenix app is a very simple one without any extra configuration. How can I connect to it with telnet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Phoenix** uses **Cowboy** as underlying webserver. It has different timeout options, but the one we need is `request_timeout`.

It defaults to `5_000` (in milliseconds) and can be changed inside configuration like this:

```rb
config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint,
  http: [
    port: ...,
    ...
    protocol_options: [
      request_timeout: 60000 # minute here - for example
    ]
  ]
```

Now, you have a minute to type your:

```
GET /
```

inside telnet CLI